# How can i add new filed in laravel 5.3 auth and this filed not mendetory for admin?

Tags: laravel-5.3

There are 3 fields :
email, password, company id

I want validation for simple user. Like check email id click on submit button when user is admin at that time company id not mandatory otherwise company id field mandatory.

Is it possible ? If possible give me solution.

Comment: try the validation 'required_if'

Comment: ''required_if" not worked.

Comment: how did you use required_if